# is there a keyword in java that's similar to swift's dynamicType

Tags: java, variables, types, dynamictype

I know that in swift, there is a keyword called variableName.**dynamicType** which identify the type of which the variable belongs to. I was just wondering if there is a similar keyword in java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `Object#getClass` (which gives you a `java.lang.Class`):

```
 Object x = new BigInteger(123);
 System.out.println(x.getClass().getSimpleName());
```